# CentOS-7 No package java-1.8.0-openjdk available

Tags: centos7, java

After attempting everything available over the net i am turning to SO to help with finding a clear solution to installing
java-1.8.0-openjdk and java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel on CentOS-7.

from all docs everywhere it must be as straight as
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk

and yet i get "No package java-1.8.0-openjdk available."

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.tripadvisor.com
 * epel: s3-mirror-us-east-1.fedoraproject.org
 * extras: mirrors.greenmountainaccess.net
 * updates: mirror.umd.edu
No package java-1.8.0-openjdk available.
Error: Nothing to do

following is my CentOS-Base.repo (pretty much stock):

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

to add, even switching to baseurl is no help.

followed:
    http://openjdk.java.net/install/

am i completely missing something trivial?

Comment: What does `yum search openjdk` say?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i was able to solve this. i had overlooked that openjdk was excluded in /etc/yum.conf

```
$ grep openjdk /etc/yum.conf
exclude=*.i?86 *openjdk* java*
```